# Usar un array de punteros en una función amiga

Tags: c++, dev-c++

estoy algo atorado con un pequeño ejercicio en C++ y quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar aquí.

En mi ejercicio definí un array de punteros en el Main, el cual con un for estará mandando objetos a la clase Producto con los atributos clave, nombre y precio. Todos los objetos se guardan sin problema, sin embargo tengo que hacer que una clase amiga llame cada objeto de ese array, lo imprima y vaya sumando el precio de cada producto para al final dar el total.

Mi problema aquí es que me da error al llamar la función amiga y ponerle como parámetro el puntero de esta manera `calculo(pro[i]);`

Aquí el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Producto.h";
using namespace std;

float calculo(Producto objeto){
    float total;
    
    cout << objeto.clave << ", " << objeto.nombre << ", " << objeto.precio << endl;;
    total += objeto.precio;
    
    
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string clave;
    string nombre;
    int cantidad;
    float precio;
    float total;
    
    
    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de productos vendidos: ";
    cin >> cantidad;
    
    Producto *pro[cantidad];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        
        cout << endl << "Clave del producto: ";
        cin >> clave;
        
        cout << "Nombre del producto: ";
        cin >> nombre;
        
        cout << "Precio del producto: ";
        cin >> precio;
        
        pro[i] = new Producto(clave, nombre, precio);
        
    }
     

    for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        
        //El error es aquí
        calculo( pro[i] );
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

La clase solo tiene el constructor default y parametrizado con los atributos.

```
#ifndef PRODUCTO_H
#define PRODUCTO_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Producto{
    private:
        string clave;
        string nombre;
        int cantidad;
        float precio;
        float total;
        
    public:
        Producto();
        Producto(string CLAVE, string NOMBRE, float PRECIO);
        
        friend float calculo(Producto, int, int);
    
};

#endif
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿De qué manera puedo utilizar los objetos del array en la función amiga?

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir tambien los contenidos de `Producto.h`?

Comment: También sería de infinita ayuda que compartas el error que obtienes.

Comment: Este es el error: [Error] could not convert 'pro[i]' from 'Producto*' to 'Producto'

Comment: Product.h: 
````
#ifndef PRODUCTO_H
#define PRODUCTO_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Producto{
 private:
  string clave;
  string nombre;
  int cantidad;
  float precio;
  float total = 0;
  
 public:
  Producto();
  Producto(string CLAVE, string NOMBRE, float PRECIO);
  
  friend float calculo(Producto, int, int);
 
};

#endif
````

Comment: Que forma mas complicada de explicar (y poner título) a un error tan simple y básico: tu variable `pro[]` es un *array* **de punteros**. Tu función `calculo( )` espera **una instancia** de un objeto, no un puntero: `calculo( *pro[i] );`